# Determine server IP address in SaaS application

Tags: web-server, cloud, dynamic-ip, saas

I have multiple clients (mobile and web) that need to connect to my application on the cloud using web services. How do I specify the IP address of the server in my client code?
Another query is - if I change the server, and go to another cloud provider and get a new IP address, would I need to change all my client applications to reflect the new IP address? Is there any other optimized way in which I would not need to change the client applications?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You don't specify the IPs on your client, **nobody** does that, you point them at the matching DNS record for your services. And for your second question you're update your DNS records to match your new IP addresses.

Please don't take this as rude or offensive but this is a very basic question that anyone with even the smallest experience with web/IP systems would know - that you're asking this question worries me that you may not have the right experience and training to be building such systems. Again I'm not being rude but it would be a bit like getting into a taxi and the driver asking you what a steering wheel was.